# How do I create a user authentication in DJANGO WITHOUT using PATH? Specifically Using Cloud9

Tags: python, django, path, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I'm a beginner to Django and trying to make a website where users can store their contacts in a list. So far I have been successful in adding list items via a form. However, I'm using cloud9 and path can't be imported and I'm trying to find a way around it but I can't. I've seen the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/) and this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication) and they both use path.

Comment: Try using `url`

Comment: Confirm that you're actually using Django 2.0+, and if not, switch to the documentation for the version you're using.

Comment: Thanks @Umair for your suggestion, but can you please show me the proper syntax for url, because I don't know how it's going to work in this case. `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`. According to the documentation, this line adds the Django site authentication urls but I don't know how I'm going to use urls if I have a "include()" in it and what view would I link it to? Any links would be helpful, thank you

Comment: @Wiggy A. thanks for your feedback and I'm in fact using `Django version 2.0.5, `, but I feel that it's just Cloud9 that's messing everything up

Answer (score 0):

Use urls
first import it with include

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
```

then this is how you switch from path to urls, quite simple actually

Take admin url for example, this is what path looks like

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

this is what urls looks like

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Good work X-TremeFighter12!